# C# Script in Unity error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm getting this weird error when trying to compile this simple console game of guessing numbers. This worked fine in my desktop but currently I'm using my laptop and can't get this WORKING game to compile. The error I get is `The associated script can not be loaded. Please fix any compile errors and assign a valid script.` I've tried from rewriting the code to testing it with simpler methods and still wont work.

Here is the code itself:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
//using System.Collections;

public class NumberWizards : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization

    int max;
    int min;
    int guess;
    //string userInput = "input";

    void Start () {
        StarGame();

    }

    void StarGame() {
        max = 1000;
        min = 1;

        print ("========================");
        print ("Welcome to Number Wizard");

//      print ("Give a max range of numbers: ");
//      userInput = Console.ReadLine();
//      max = Convert.ToInt32(userInput);
//      
//      
//      print ("Give a min range of numbers: ");
//      userInput = Console.ReadLine();
//      min = Convert.ToInt32(userInput);
//      
//      while(min == max) {
//          Console.WriteLine("The ranges must be different!");
//          print ("Give a min range of numbers: ");
//          userInput = Console.ReadLine();
//          min = Convert.ToInt32(userInput);
//          
//      }
        max = max +1;
        guess = max - min;
        print("Think of a number and don't tell me. ");

        print ("The highest number you can pick is " +  max); 
        print ("The lowest number you can pick is " + min);     
        print ("Is the number higher or lower than "  + guess);
        print ("Up arrow = higher, down = lower, return = equal");

    }

    void NextGuess() {

        guess = (max + min) / 2;
        print ("Higher or lower than " + guess);
        print ("Up arrow = higher, down = lower, return = equal");

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow)) {
            //print("Up arrow key was pressed");

            min = guess;
            NextGuess();


        }else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow)) {
            //print("Down arrow key was pressed");

            max = guess;
            NextGuess();

        } else if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Return)) {
            print("I won");
            StarGame();
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a list of things to check.

1. Ensure that there is no compile time errors. Building in MonoDevelop, and verify there are no errors on the console in Unity.
2. Ensure that the name of the class matches the file name. This was my mistake;-)
3. Try switching out the script and putting something else in, to see if there was a glitch of sorts.

Answer (score -1):

The error means that you have your class called something else than NumberWizards.cs, unfortunately while you can generally name your files as you want in C#, MonoBehaviours kinda need to be placed in correctly named files if you want UnityEditor to see them